# Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string | boolean | string[]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to check if `option` is available in my `question` objects' `answer` property.
My checkbox is as following

```
<Checkbox
    checked={
    question.answer.includes(option.toString())
                        ? true
                        : false
    }
    // onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

and my types for question onbect is as following

```
export type Question = {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  question: string;
  sideA?: string[];
  sideB?: string[];
  options: string[] | boolean[];
  correctAnswer: string | boolean | string[];
  answer: string | boolean | null | string[];
  isAnswered: boolean;
};
```

Comment: What happens if `answer` is a boolean? Or `null`? Then calling `includes()` on them would throw an error. If was just a plain string then it won't throw an error but it's not necessarily correct to check for a substring.

Comment: Then how to write this correctly? @VLAZ

Comment: You either adjust your type because it's wrong or the type is right and you need to change your code to work with it. I don't know which one is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You define `answer: string | boolean | null | string[]`, and as far as I know, `includes` doesn't exists on `boolean` nor `null`